# Python programming using API error

Tags: python, json, api

I'm new to the programming API's, I'm trying to write my bot to run on a site and this is the doc to the API [Crypto-games API doc site](https://api.crypto-games.net/) but I get the `400 error` on execution for the place bet command and the error won't print out the error content, just the error code. Here is what they gave on their site

```
URL: /v1/placebet/:coin/:key
{ "Bet": 0.00001024, "Payout": 2.0, "UnderOver": true, "ClientSeed": "somerandomseed" }
UnderOver is target result. Example: < 49.600 or > 50.399`
```

And here's a sample Javascript they gave

```
var input = { Bet: 0.00001024, Payout: 2.0, UnderOver: true,
ClientSeed: "somerandomseed" };
$.ajax({
  url: "https://api.crypto-games.net/v1/placebet/BTC/7Ii8vdPBUBfTPHcuzkHuhftkGD43iWwbFkdwBQa7GL8R4AwBr3",
  data: JSON.stringify(input),
  dataType: "json",
  contentType: "application/json",
  type: "POST",
  success: function (r) {
        console.log(r);
  }
});
```

here is the Python code I wrote to run the placebet command

```
import requests
import json

parameter = {"Bet": 10.0000000, "Payout":2.0, " >50.399": True, "ClientSeed": "CTThgTlac54qK2lahvLicrFlJsJmSIEkRMt4VcuN"}
parameters = json.dumps(parameter)
response = requests.get("https://api.crypto-games.net/v1/placebet/PLAY/XxxMyAPIHerexxX", params = parameters)
print(response.content)
print(response.status_code)
```

I tried running it without the `json.dumps()` but I still get the same output. Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong, all criticism and suggestions are welcome.

Comment: You don't need the `json.dumps()`, but you do need to make it a `requests.post` function call instead.

Comment: Thank you, I was careless with that, I need be more careful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Place bet](https://api.crypto-games.net/#Place_bet_0) docs (and in the example code pasted), it's supposed to be a `POST` request, not `GET`.

```
response = requests.post(...)
```

---

Edit: I think your `params` in the request should be `data` instead, since params are sent with the URL and stringified data goes in the request body/data. (The `json.dumps()` is correct.)

```
parameters = json.dumps(parameter)
response = requests.post("https://api.crypto-games.net/v1/placebet/PLAY/XxxMyAPIHerexxX",
                         data=parameters)
```

<strike>And you can send [JSON data in the body](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) without it if you're on a more recent version of `requests`</strike>:

> ```
> >>> url = 'https://api.github.com/some/endpoint'
> >>> payload = {'some': 'data'}
>
> >>> r = requests.post(url, json=payload)
> ```

---

Edit 2:

`"UnderOver": true` is mandatory in the data  to be sent. Their examples are unclear about how that is supposed to be translated to a number. I think that's the `Bet` value (so +/- the Bet amount). So try:

```
parameter = {"Bet": 10.0000000, "Payout":2.0, "UnderOver": True, "ClientSeed": "CTThgTlac54qK2lahvLicrFlJsJmSIEkRMt4VcuN"}
```

Also, don't use `requests.post(url, json=payload)` method because it translates Python's `True` to the js string `"True"` instead of js boolean `true`. So stick with `parameters = json.dumps(parameter)` method, but still as data.

Wrt "Content-Type" error, add this to your request:

```
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
response = requests.post("https://api.crypto-games.net/v1/placebet/PLAY/XxxMyAPIHerexxX",
                         data=parameters,
                         headers=headers)
```

Comment: I think your `params` in the request should be `data` instead, since params are sent with the URL and stringified data goes in the body/data.

Comment: I tried switching things around but I still get the `invalid parameter` error, my guess is it has to do with the `UnderOver` I don't fully understand how to represent it 
      
    
    
  `>>> parameter = {"Bet": 10.0000000, "Payout":2.0, "Over": True, "ClientSeed": "CTThgTlac54qK2lahvLicrFlJsJmSIEkRMt4VcuN"}`
    `>>> response = requests.post(_url, json = parameter)`

Comment: Sorry about the comment above, looks messy, but when I use `data = parameters` I get this error `The request contains an entity body but no Content-Type header. The inferred media type 'application/octet-stream' is not supported for this resource.`

Comment: I've edited to add a headers param. From your URL, is the coin you're betting on a coin called _"PLAY"_? And you didn't do `parameters = json.dumps(parameter)`, you used `paramter` without the `s`.

Comment: You've been very helpful to me today, thank you very much, it's working now. I left the `"UnderOver": True"` the same, I guess T/F for under/over.

Comment: You're welcome. Wrt UnderOver, I meant `" >50.399": True` should be, as you put `"UnderOver": True` (boolean, not string), not a `number: True`.